# TFIDF score into percentage

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I currently have a search system that displays percentage of found words in the database. I'm thinking of moving to elastic search, but I still want the results to be displayed as percentage. Is it possible? Currently in Kibana I have an explain function that displays for example the "value" : 0.6931471, How can I convert it to percentage to be used in my system?

Thank you for answers

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#scripted_similarity